# Laravel database query builder find::with just one record

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm trying to get 1 phone from the database with the storageoptions of that phone. This solution gives me all phones, with their storage options:

```
$phones = Phone::with('storageOptions')->get();
```

Now this solution gives me just 1 phone, with its 3 storage options, except that it gives the same phone 3 times:

```
$phone = Phone::find($phone->id)
        ->join('storage_options', 'phones.id', '=', 'storage_options.phone_id')
        ->where('storage_options.phone_id', '=', $phone->id)
        ->get();
```

Now I thought to be a smartass and just try this line of code:

```
$phone = Phone::find($phone->id)->with('storageOptions')->get();
```

Except that that last line gives back all phones, and not their storage options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`with()` is a query modifier. `find()` and `get()` are query executers. You just need to make sure you place all your query modifiers before you execute the query:

```
$phone = Phone::with('storageOptions')->find($phone->id);
```

---

I noticed that you're trying to fetch the phone while already having the `$phone` populated. If you already have the phone, and you're just trying to load the storage options, you can use the `load()` method, or just access the relationship attribute and the relationship will be lazy loaded:

```
// manually load the relationship on an existing record
$phone->load('storageOptions');

// or, just access the relationship property to lazy load the relationship
dd($phone->storageOptions);
```